# How do I reset MONGO_URL to its default value in meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

While trying to run meteor for the first time.. the application struck at 'starting your app'....

I followed [this](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-stuck-at-starting-your-app/25592/6#post_7) solution.. and did this

`set MONGO_URL=''`

The application instance started but now
How do I reset the value of MONGO_URL to its default value.i.e. 
I've tried : 
`meteor reset`  but it doesn't resets the value of MONGO_URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be clear: `meteor reset` resets you database files if you are running using the built-in MongoDB. What you want to do unset your shell environment variable. So, assuming you are on windows (because of the solution you linked to):

```
set MONGO_URL=
```

(no space or anything after the `=`)